# Google maps нельзя нажать на маркер под маркером

Tags: javascript, google-maps

Как сделать, так, чтобы если маркер под маркером, чтобы все прокликивались?
Кликнул на 1 появился 2, кликнул на 2 появился 3, кликнул на 3, если нет больше маркеров, то появится 1.
Как у 2gis работает, не пойму, как сделать, чтобы также было на google-map.
Пожалуйста подскажите, если ли решение?

Comment: В js, при клике формируется event, у него есть метод stopPropagation, вы пробовали копать в эту сторону? Суть в том, что, js в таких случаях (когда под клик попадают несколько объектов), по умолчанию оповещает ВСЕХ кто попал под клик, но, в порядке очереди (чем ближе слой к пользователю, тем "первей" его оповестят, в "стопке" с z-order:1 и z-order:2, первого оповестят у кого будет z-order:2), но, как раз stopPropagation, позволяет остановить механизм оповещения, и завершить "раздачу кликов".

Comment: Если отталкиваться от этого, вам необходимо обойти эту остановку, но сделать этот обход выборочным (нас интересуют только маркеры), и вместо передачи кликов, сначала, надо составить список тех кто попал под этот клик, а уже потом, в самом конце, решать, кого оповестить об этом событии.

Comment: @test123, покажите решение, а то не понятно, о чем речь. Или хотя-бы пример какой-то, как это сделать или обойти.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Получилось решить так (с сохранением индексов):

```
marker.addListener('click', function () {
    infowindow.setContent(info[this.position]);
    infowindow.open(chart, this);
    var idx = this.getZIndex();
    if (0 !== idx) {
         if (1 === idx) {
             for (var key in jsons) {
                  jsons.hasOwnProperty(key) && marks[key].setZIndex(oldMarks[key]);
             }
             return;
         }
         this.setZIndex(0);
    } else {
         for (var key in jsons) {
              jsons.hasOwnProperty(key) && marks[key].setZIndex(oldMarks[key]);
         }
    }
});
```

Теперь все работает.